# New Relic Memcached plugin installation location - App server or memcached server(s)?

Tags: memcached

We have the New Relic PHP agent running on our 8 app servers. we have two memcached servers and would like to add the New Relic/ Meet Me Memcached plugin to grab memcached metrics. Should the memcached plugin be installed on the app servers or memcached servers? I read up on the installation instructions however this is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Should the memcached plugin be installed on the app servers or memcached servers?

the meetme newrelic plugin can be run on either the mc boxes, your app box, or even a central command/control box that connects to all of your farm.

the latest version of the meetme plugin supports multiple instances of the same service check, so in pre-1.0.14, you would need to run the plugin on the same host you are monitoring.

also, if you are running 1.0.12, and want to upgrade (so the same command/control box can monitor your whole farm... ie running newrelic plugin on your nagios box), please be aware of this:

> Version 1.0.12 has a SERIOUS uninstallation bug in the file manifest that will remove all the files on your filesystem if you try and do a pip remove newrelic_plugin_agent.

how about that for a feature?